# 2011 Chrysler Town & Country not staying started after I jump it

Tags: electrical, chrysler, town-and-country

I replaced my alternator and battery but as soon as I remove the jumper cables my car dies on my 2011 Chrysler Town & Country

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you personally install the new battery and alternator?

Comment: Did you need to jump start the vehicle even though you had installed a new battery?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you pull the cables and it dies, this is a sign the alternator is not working. Even though you just replaced it, it could be bad. I'd take it back to the store and have them retest it for you, but I'm betting it is bad. And yes, new alternators can be bad. You should have them test it before you leave the store.